# Creating an Oracle Db in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

I am trying to see if there is an easy way to setup my Oracle SQL Developer so that I can run everything though it but store data on my AWS account (free tier). I tried creating a RDS (which will likely expire after 12 months) database and used the endpoint + port to create a new database connection in SQL developer and even with the correct username/password it errors out the below message.

To be clear, I am trying to do what this guy did in his video but I am receiving an error. I think something might be wrong with my security group. The group type that he used is not an attribute of the current drop down options in there. I was thinking perhaps there is another way of doing it, such as a SSH or something of that nature.

[YouTube Link](http://youtu.be/iU4Q4Tv822Q)

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: It is not really clear what you've done and why it's not working, maybe add more details? A wild guess: check if RDS instance has it's ports open, and whether network rules allow outside connections.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is specifically designed to talk to Oracle databases, and that's it. It has no relation to DynamoDB.

Comment: I am new to AWS, so perhaps my title description wasn't accurate enough to get my objective through. I am trying to do this: https://youtu.be/iU4Q4Tv822Q

Answer (score 1):

No.

AWS Dynamo is not a relational DB...it does not understand SQL.

Comment: This video suggest that you can (but is outdated): https://youtu.be/iU4Q4Tv822Q

Comment: @AndrewHicks that video shows creating an Oracle Db in AWS...not connecting to a AWS Dynamo DB with Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Excuse my lack of understanding on AWS, I am rather new to it. That is what I am trying to do: Use oracle developer to store tables on AWS (through AWS's Dynamo DB instance via RDS).